# slider function to calculate a single value before certain days on a time series

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, tidyverse

I have a data frame (test_copy) as follows. I am trying to calculate the amount of A 24 hr before each particular date using the slide function below.

```
Aat24hrbfor  = slide(test_copy$A, ~.x, .before = 3, .complete = TRUE)
```

The code calculates a series of values (`c(0.01, 0.04, 0.04, 0.03)`) instead of calculating a value 24 hrs before a particular date and time.

[eg: I wanted to calculate the value of A on 2022020200 before 24 hrs, then the result should be 0.01 (that is the value of A at 2022020100)]

How would I fix the code? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

| date | A | B | C | D | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022020100 | 0.01 | 0.03 | 0.02 | 0.1 | 0.24 |
| 2022020106 | 0.04 | 0.01 | 0.01 | 0.03 | 0.09 |
| 2022020112 | 0.04 | 0.01 | 0.01 | 0.02 | 0.09 |
| 2022020118 | 0.03 | 0.01 | 0.00 | 0.02 | 0.06 |
| 2022020200 | 0.02 | 0.01 | 0.00 | 0.01 | 0.05 |
| 2022020206 | 0.04 | 0.03 | 0.01 | 0.02 | 0.01 |
| 2022020212 | 0.09 | 0.02 | 0.03 | 0.05 | 0.19 |
| 2022020218 | 0.10 | 0.00 | 0.04 | 0.05 | 0.19 |

Comment: `Aat24hrbfor = dplyr::lag(test_copy$A, 4)`?

Comment: `Aat24hrbfor = as.numeric(slider::slide(test_copy$A, ~.x, .before = 4, .after = -4))` or `Aat24hrbfor = slider::slide_dbl(test_copy$A, ~.x, .before = 4, .after = -4, .complete = TRUE)`